# Eliminar todos los puntos con gsub

Tags: regex, r

Quiero saber cómo corregir el código para borrar un caracter (punto) en una variable de número de identidad (Ej: `"2.564.752"` convertir a `"2564752"`).

En lugar de borrar solo ese caracter, termina borrando toda mi variable, ¿tendrían alguna sugerencia?

```
becal_cobertura = gsub('.', '', becal_cobertura)
```

Comment: No es un lenguaje que conozca ni cómo trabaja la función pero me atrevo a proponer que quizá escapando el punto `\.`

Comment: Decis agregando \? ahora lo probe pero no reconoce el elemento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que el caracter punto/dot `.` tiene un significado especial en las expresiones regulares, es como un comodín, representa cualquier caracter. Para poder buscar literalmente el `.` puedes escaparlo usando `\` de la siguiente forma:

```
gsub('\\.', '', '2.564.752')
[1] "2564752"
```

Nota: En `R`  para indicar la barra invertida hay que escribirla de forma doble `\\`.

O Eventualmente

```
gsub('[.]', '', '2.564.752')
[1] "2564752"
```

Y por último, pero sin usar expresiones regulares, puedes hacer:

```
gsub('.', '', '2.564.752', fixed = T)
[1] "2564752"
```

Comment: Funciono!! muchisimas gracias!